# Mutagen's OggFileType producing 'Type Error: NoneType' exception

Tags: python, metadata, ogg, mutagen

Ive just started using mutagen and have succefully used it with *m4a*, *mp3*, *ape*, *afs*, and *flac*. However Im having difficulty with the OggFileType class, when I try to create an instance of OggFileType Im presented with a `"TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable"` exception.

Iv searched and searched for solutions but information and documentation on mutagen is  scarce. Any help would be appreciated thanks.

**A snippet of the code I am using for testing**

```
path = "I:\Music\Various Artists\Studio One Classics"
audiofile = "16 - Rub A Dub Style.ogg"
os.chdir(path)
OggTag = OggFileType(audiofile)
print OggTag
```

**Traceback**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "I:\My Documents\Programming\python\music_organizer\mutagen_test.py", line 203, in <module>
    OggTag = OggFileType(audiofile)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\mutagen\__init__.py", line 75, in __init__
    self.load(filename, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\mutagen\ogg.py", line 441, in load
    self.info = self._Info(fileobj)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not supposed to use OggFileType directly.  It's a base class for the other Ogg format classes -- OggVorbis, OggTheora, etc.  Those all properly set _Info, _Tags, _Error appropriately.  This is noted in the documentation for the ogg.py module:

> Read and write Ogg bitstreams and pages.
>
> This module reads and writes a subset of the Ogg bitstream format
> version 0. It does *not* read or write Ogg Vorbis files! For that,
> you should use mutagen.oggvorbis.

Comment: I was sure I had already read that doc string -obviously not. Thanks